How can I delete a specific record from my AWS Glue table?
How can I delete a specific record from my AWS Glue table using Python?
My table is linked to an S3 bucket that contains multiple files.
So far, the only method I've found to delete a row/record is by deleting the file in the bucket, either using boto3.delete_object or purge_s3_path.
In both cases, you need to first identify the exact file containing the data you want to remove (I’m still unsure how to handle that part).
However, it's common for these files to contain multiple records.
As a result, simply deleting the entire file isn't feasible, which introduces additional complexity.
Note that the solution need to work with any type of file (CSV, JSON, etc...).

This is only possible on Iceberg-format files, since they include a 'log' that acts as an override for the data contained in the files. See: Can I delete data (rows in tables) from Athena? - Stack Overflow

If I would say that all the file format in my bucket are always parquet, would there be any solution?

Iceberg and Delta are variations on top of Parquet files -- the data is kept in Parquet, but then a 'log' keeps track of changes like updates and deletes. You might be able to convert the format with little effort, see: Migrating Glue Data Catalog tables to use Apache Iceberg open table format using Athena | AWS re:Post
